# How to know if android purchase data is sandbox or not (Testing or not)?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, sandbox, android-inapp-purchase

we have implemented android in app purchase   , we are sending purchase info to our  Backend , **my Question is How to know if  purchase data is sandbox or not ?**  before google  update testing env  the order id for testing was null , now google is return and order id for testing env,
 there is a docs from google for  success response data
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html

but there is no value shows that we are in testing env

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell the difference.

The "sandbox" purchases are made to simulate real purchases. You can't tell the difference between them by intent (in code, you can tell it by the fact that you don't get any money from it, but the app can't tell the difference)

Google Play and the backend there (that handles the actual purchase flow, you don't have any control over that) obviously knows. But nothing is sent to the app that tells whether it's a sandbox purchase or not